# How can I print content from an array inside each_with_index based on the index?

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [{:item => 'apple', :quantity => 92}, {:item => 'banana', :quantity => 43}, {:item => 'kiwi', :quantity => 55}]
```

And I want an output like so:

```
1. apple 92 2. banana 43 3. kiwi 55
```

Now, as it is important that each item in array `b` is aligned with the order of the values in array `a`, I decided to write an `each_with_index` loop so that I would be able to extract data at the desired position from array `b`:

```
a.each_with_index do |a_value, i| 
  puts a_value 
  puts '.' 
  puts b[i][:item] 
  puts b[i][:quantity]
end
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):8:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):8:in `each'
    from (irb):8:in `each_with_index'
    from (irb):8
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'
```

Which I find rather strange, because the hash at that position isn't empty.

If I print the entire content of the array at that position it works, for example:

```
a.each_with_index do |a_value, i| 
  puts b[i]
end
```

Which gives:

```
{:item => 'apple', :quantity => 92} 
{:item => 'banana', :quantity => 43} 
{:item => 'kiwi', :quantity => 55}
```

but I can't specify a key inside the hash to print the content of? What's up with that?

Comment: No, updated the code in my question

Comment: Do `p b[i]` instead of `puts b[i]`. One of your hashes is nil (when you think it isn't)

Comment: Ah, that was the issue, post this as an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: @bork what about the last example with `puts b[i]` – how could that possibly work if one of the hashes is in fact `nil`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I can't specify a key inside the hash to print the content of? What's up with that?

This doesn't make sense, of course. If you have a hash, you can get its keys/values. The problem here is that you *don't* have a hash. Instead, one of your `b[i]` is nil (which triggers the error).

Check this by printing them with `p b[i]` instead of `puts b[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `a` array

```
b.map(&:values).map.with_index {|(item, quantity), index| 
 "#{index + 1}. #{item} #{quantity}"
}.join(' ')
=> "1. apple 92 2. banana 43 3. kiwi 55"
```

Comment: FWIW, `with_index` accepts an argument for starting index. `.with_index(1)` allows to avoid nasty `#{index + 1`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev that’s why it has “FWIW” opening :) Turns out I cannot do Ruby anymore, it literally hurts. The language is so stupid :-P

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [{:item => 'apple', :quantity => 92}, {:item => 'banana', :quantity => 43}, {:item => 'kiwi', :quantity => 55}]

a.each_with_index do |a_value, i| 
  puts "#{a_value}. #{b[i][:item]} #{b[i][:quantity]}"
end
```

this will output:

```
1. apple 92
2. banana 43
3. kiwi 55
```

OR if you want to have an output like

```
1. apple 92 2. banana 43 3. kiwi 55
```

then you can use map with index

```
output = a.map.with_index do |a_value, i| 
  "#{a_value}. #{b[i][:item]} #{b[i][:quantity]}"
end.join(' ')
puts output
```

Comment: This is not any different from what they're doing.